# How to save data to file in such a way that it is easy to access specific member of data without loading/parsing entire file?

Tags: database, memory, data-structures, rust, io

I have a struct filled with data in a tree data structure. Something like this in Rust:

```
struct MyData {
    // ...
    // Metadata
    nested_data: Vec<MyNestedData>
}
struct MyNestedData {
    // ...
    // MetaData
    nested_nested_data: Vec<MyNestedNestedData>
}
// ...etc...etc
// And so it continues until lowest level.
```

I want to save this to a file, then read value of one single specific branch e.g.:

`mydata.nested_data[3].{...}.nested_nested_nested_nested_data[14].specific_data`

quickly without going through entire file, or loading this file to memory (RAM efficient).

What is the best way to do this? What tools exist for this? Theory? Anything would be of help!

Ideally data would be saved in a compact state (binary, but no compression for fastest read speed), and there would be no need to introduce database management system.

I already have a system working with serialization/de-serialization, but it is slow since it de-serializes entire file and stores it to memory each time my program is called just to access one data member. And this program will be used as a module in another program that will send queries to it many times a second.

Comment: The typical solution here would be to include a table at the beginning of the file that indicates the offset and size of each member. When you need to retrieve something, you look up its offset in the table, seek to that position in the file and then deserialize it.

Comment: I was thinking of that. Do you know if there is a module for that? Or I have to implement it myself